# Exception handlers should preserve the original exception : Either log or rethrow this exception

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1

This is my method, when  I try to analyze my code by sonarQube am getting this error:

Exception handlers should preserve the original exception : Either log or rethrow this exception.

Why am getting this error, should I not catch the exception like my method?

my method :

```
for (String QT : Q_T) {

                try {
                        // some logic 
                    }

                } catch (JsonParseException e) {                    
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
                } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what it's trying to tell you is to log the `Exception` as it is, not the `toString()` version, like [here](https://sonar43.spring.io/rules/show/squid:S1166?layout=false), also adding some 'context' or information to the `log`

```
for (String QT : Q_T) {
        try {
            // some logic 
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {                    
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "context", e);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "context", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "context", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "context", e);
        }
}
```